# spring-boot swagger-ui in docker container returns 404

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, swagger-ui, openapi

I want to deploy my spring-boot application into docker container.
I have a locally working application where my swagger ui works perfectly.

So if i start my application outside docker container, open url in browser http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui/index.html
the ui loads and works.

If i start the application in docker, url just returns 404.
Of course the application starts in docker, only swagger-ui returns 404.
The api endpoints are working so I can reach the application.

My swagger configuration is only consists adding the dependency into pom:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8090
ARG JAR_FILE=server/target/the-application.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The spring boot version i am using is 2.7.1

I am starting the application in docker with the following command: (I run the application with the same dev environment outside of docker)

docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -p 8090:8090 the-application:latest .

I have no idea what can be wrong here, should i need to change something in the configuration just for work in docker? Or maybe my Dockerfile is wrong?

Comment: One thing to check is whether the Swagger UI is being served on a different port than your API endpoints. By default, the SpringDoc OpenAPI UI should be available at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, but if your API endpoints are being served on a different port (e.g. 8090), you may need to configure the Swagger UI to use that port.

Another thing to check is whether your Docker container is actually exposing port 8090. You've specified the -p 8090:8090 option when running your container, which should map port 8090 in the container to port 8090 on your host machine.

Comment: However, it's possible that there's a conflict with another service running on port 8090 on your host machine. To check if this is the case, you can try changing the port mapping to something like -p 8080:8090, which would map port 8090 in the container to port 8080 on your host machine.

Comment: I encountered the same issue after containerizing the project with the following version:
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui')
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-oas:3.0.0')